# Ellipse representation

Tags: conic-sections

> The equation $\frac{x^2}{2-a}+\frac{y^2}{a-5} +1 = 0$ represents an ellipse if $a\; \epsilon$
>   (A) $(2,\frac{3}{2})\;\cup\;(\frac{3}{2},5)$
>   (B) $(2,\frac{3}{2})$
>   (C) $(1,\frac{3}{2})$
>   (D) $(\frac{3}{2},5)$

This is what I have done,

For representing an ellipse,
 $$e<1$$
 $$\implies \sqrt{1-\frac{a-5}{2-a}} <1$$
 $$\implies 1-\frac{a-5}{2-a}<1$$
 $$\implies \frac{a-5}{2-a}>0$$
 $$\implies \frac{a-5}{a-2}<0$$

So, $a\;\epsilon\;(2,5)$
But there are no such options. So, have I missed a solution ? I think there is a mistake in the way I have solved the problem. Can anybody tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

you should exclude the case of $e=0$, which is a circle but not a ellipse. So the answer is A.

**Additional notes**

I think the $3/2$ in all your options should be $7/2$. Otherwise $(2,3/2)$ does not make any sense.

Comment: Why did you choose $\frac 72$?  Because it is the center of the interval $(2,5)$?  Note that if all the $\frac32$ points are misprints and a valid value is inserted equally into each, then $(C)$ is the only remaining incorrect answer...

Comment: @abiessu (1)Because $7/2$ makes it a circle. (2)I agree with you the problem asks only for sufficient conditions, so in that sense B,D are also correct answer.  (3) In general actually I think the definition of ellipse include the case of a circle. (4) My understanding is that this is just a poorly phrased problem....

Comment: You are right, it should be $\frac{7}{2}$. And it's not my fault that it's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

If

$$\frac {x^2}{2-a}+\frac{y^2}{a-5}+1=0$$

is claimed to be an ellipse, then in standard form,

$$\frac {x^2}{a-2}+\frac{y^2}{5-a}=1$$

which matches exactly with the result that you found, namely that $a\in(2,5)$.

The listed answer in $(A)$ is not correct as written, but the writing of it suggests that perhaps it is written incorrectly and might be something like $(2,\frac 52)\cup (\frac 52,5)$.  But if that were the case, then (presumably) $(B),(D)$ would also have the same mixup and would also be correct answers.

Basically, you found the correct interval for $a$, I would go back to the source of the question and make sure that nothing is misprinted or mis-copied...

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, because $\frac{3}{2}$ is not giving me equal denominators but $\frac{7}{2}$ is giving me equal denominators which, in turn gives me a circle. As, we are considering a general ellipse, so, we have to exclude $\frac{7}{2}$ from the solution set. I think what MoonKnight has written may be right.

Comment: Also, note that $\frac 72=3\frac 12$ which may have contributed to the confusion initially...

Comment: That just means that someone (along the chain of you receiving the problem to solve) may have looked at $3\frac12$ on one sheet and incorrectly written $\frac32$ on another...

Answer (score 0):

If we agree in $(2,3/2)=\emptyset$ and notice that there is an *if* and no *iff*, then there are two interpretations depending on we consider a circle as an ellipse or not. In the first case A, C, and D are correct, otherwise C is the only correct solution.

Comment: Umm, I think $(C)$ is the only interval written correctly, and it is non-empty and disjoint with the solution space for $a$ and therefore cannot be the correct answer...